# What are the default permissions for the /sbin/ directory?

Tags: permissions

Pulled a `chmod 777 /` on accident yesterday, I've recovered almost all of the permissions except a few folders, and I can't find what default permissions for `/sbin/` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

755 is the magic number you are looking for :)